# Copula with a certain correlation

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, copula

What does it mean for values to be "drawn from a normal copula with correlation $\rho\in [0, 1]$"? Is that a normal distribution with a covariance matrix whose entries are uniform random in $[0, 1]$?

Would sampling from a multivariate normal distribution using a probability package  (like numpy) be equivalent to "drawn from a normal copula with correlation $\rho\in [0, 1]$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly does **not** mean what you suggest. The number $\rho\in[0,1]$ is **not** random.

It means you have two random variables $U,V,$ each marginally uniformly distributed, so that $X = \Phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}^{-1}(U)$ and $Y=\Phi_{\nu,\tau^2}^{-1}(V)$ are normally distributed, and and the joint distribution of $U,V$ is such that

- $\operatorname{corr}(X,Y)=\rho,$ and
- Every constant (i.e. non-random) linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ is normally distributed.

You can also do this with more than two random variables, in which case the correlation between any two of them is $\rho.$

The joint distribution of $(U,V)$ is the **copula.** Generally, a copula is a multivariate distribution whose marginals are $\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1).$

Comment: I thought the goal was to get values that are marginally uniform but jointly normal+correlated. But aren't the variables X and Y you construct also marginally normally distributed instead of marginally uniform like we wanted? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @histrionics : The components $U,V$ of the copula are marginally uniform. Marginally uniform random variables cannot be jointly normal. It is $X,Y$ that are jointly normal. Jointly normally distributed random variables are not components of any copula.

Comment: But why do you construct jointly normal X, Y? I thought our goal was to get 2 correlated uniform variables, isn't it? I should have said "correlated" instead of "jointly+correlated" in my last comment.

Comment: @histrionics : How could anyone know what the _goal_ is given only what little your question says? Your question refers to a "normal copula". That phrase means something. That's why normally distributed random variables are involved.

Comment: @MichaelHardy If a copula is a multivariate distribution whose marginals, $u$ and $v$, are Uniform(0,1) and are random variables, I was wondering, separate from the  original question: what then is the **expected value of uniform marginals**, $\mathbb{E}(u)=?$ and $\mathbb{E}(v)=$?

Comment: @develarist : I wonder if I understand what you have in mind? The expected value of the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ is $1/2. \qquad$